# how to create my own delegate(protocol) in swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I am new in swift and i want to create the protocol in swift. Same thing i do in objective c.

```
@protocol CustomURLConnectionDelegate;

    @interface CustomURLConnection : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>
    {
        //Data
        NSMutableData *receivedData;

        //Connection
        NSURLConnection *urlConnection;

    }
//Delegate for Protocol
@property(nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<CustomURLConnectionDelegate> delegate;


//Init Method
-(CustomURLConnection *)initURLConnectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request withTag:(NSInteger)apiTag;  
@end
    @protocol CustomURLConnectionDelegate <NSObject>
    @optional
    -(void)getReceivedData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withTag:(NSInteger)dataTag;
    -(void)getReceivedData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withTag:(NSInteger)dataTag withObj:(NSObject *)obj;
    -(void)getDidFail:(NSString *)error withTag:(NSInteger)dataTag;
    -(void)bytesReturn:(float)returnBytes expectedTotalBytes:(float)totalBytes withTag:(int)progressTag;
    @end
```

But How can do same thing in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Apple documentation about protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html). Simply shown you can make protocols like that:

```
protocol YourProtocolName {
// protocol definition goes here
}
```

And to call it:

```
weak var delegate:YourProtocolName?
```

Comment: yes i do the same thing but in objective c we declare the `@property(nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<CustomURLConnectionDelegate> delegate;` How can i do same thing in swift?

Comment: and one more thing that i ask in objective c we declare protocol first and later we have implement should same thing we do in swift or declare and implement at one place?

Comment: In Swift you can do it in one place because there is no header file.

Comment: @ChristianWoerz You should probably declare it as `weak var delegate: YourProtocolName?` instead, and call it like this: `delegate?.someMethod()`. Avoid `!` when you can.